# Kali Linux: USB drive cannot be formatted by cryptsetup; Device is in use: error code -1 "wrong or missing parameters"

Tags: kali-linux, usb-drive, luks, cryptsetup

I am trying to make a Kali Live drive with a 32gb flash drive, using LUKS encryption for the persistence, following the instructions on this page:
https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

After running

```
cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdc
```

I get

```
Device /dev/sdc is in use. Can not proceed with format operation.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

According to the filesystem, sdc is not mounted, so I do not see how it can be "in use." Am I correct in thinking that the "wrong parameter" is the sdc itself, since it is "in use"?

Comment: You have to encrypt *the partition* ie `/dev/sdc2`, not the *device* `/dev/sdc`.

Comment: Look at the example in the guide: `cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/*sdb3*`

Comment: *sdc is not mounted*. What the system mounts are the *partitions* `/dev/sdxX`, not the *devices* `/dev/sdx`. Your `/dev/sdc` is in use because has partitions, presumably `/dev/sdc1` mounted